# Using SQL, Pseudo code for finding whether subscriber is active or not in the given two groups in facets(Healthcare)

Tags: sql, plsql, facet, informatica-powercenter, tidal-scheduler

`As per the screenshot, the requirement states whether the subscriber id is active or not in the given groups (W0051752 and E0001000).

1. If subscriber present in either W0051752 or E0001000 then it is active
2. If subscriber present in both the groups means it is inactive and it will log an error in CDM table(table which store the list of errors for future reference).
3. If subscriber present in any other groups then it will log an error.

Can you please check screenshot that I have attached and help me to solve the requirement using SQL

CASE
when (case
when (grp_id ='E0001000' || grp_id ='W0051752')  then  err_cd ='v'
when (grp_id ='E0001000' &  grp_id ='W0051752')  then  err_cd ='E'
`else err_cd ='E'`

NOTE: grp_id, err_cd are the variables that I have declared

This is the pseudo code i have tried for the given requirement but not getting the correct output. Here I have not given the condition whether the subscriber is active or not. I don't know how to proceed further.`

Comment: Change **||** to **OR**. Change **&** to **AND**. See [logical operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-9D19FEBB-A397-47F5-A4EC-D71B0DE91738).

Answer (score 0):

informatica doesnt have case when, you can use `IIF()` or decode instead. So, you can change your code like below.
In exp transformations add this var port.

```
v_err_cd = 
IIF(
grp_id ='E0001000' AND grp_id ='W0051752', 'E',
IIF( grp_id ='E0001000' OR grp_id ='W0051752', 'v', 'E'
))
```

Pls note i put AND in the beginning because in your case even if one condition is true, you will get `V` as output.